# Questions about battery power supply and voltage regulator

Tags: power-supply, batteries, capacitor, voltage-regulator

1. I have a L7805ACP Voltage regulator and a 22 uF Brownout protection Capacitor. I don't know how to hook them up though. Does the capacitor come before the regulator in the circuit, and where do I line the pins up etc? I just don't know how to place it correctly.
2. The L7805ACP regulator says operates at 10V-35V, so I obviously assume that a 9V battery is out of the question. My question is should I use 8x 1.5V AA batteries or 10 of them? Like will the 10 batteries last longer or still drain at the same rate? Or maybe someone can reccomend a battery supply?

Comment: Can you clarify your answer? What do you mean by "line the pins up"? How much current do you expect to draw from the regulated 5 volt output?

Comment: What load current are you taking on the 5v circuit?

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at this answer [Reducing 12V to 5V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109039/reducing-12v-to-5v/109041#109041). If you're using battery, the 22uF capacitor is not required for filtering.
2. The voltage drop across this IC is 2V according to the [datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/171365/STMICROELECTRONICS/L7805ACP.html). This means it will work as long as the battery voltage is greater than 7V.

Comment: No, you can't eliminate the capacitors just because the primary supply is a battery. The capacitors also provide high frequency stability. See section 5 of the datasheet. Also, the __typical__ voltage drop is 2 V but the part may require more, and the specifications are for a voltage of 2.5 V or 3.0 V. Designing to the typical value is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

9 volt battery is ok in your described use. The 7805 will be happy with at least 7.5 volts applied to it's input.

Your "brown out" capacitor on the input of the 7805 is also ok. The L7805ACP you are using needs capacitors on input and output as shown : 
[image]

Your additional 22uf capacitor "before" the regulator, on the input (Vi) is ok for your "brown out" design desires.

Look up the data sheet for your specific regulator, since variations can occur between manufacturers.
 [image]