# Can I damage a device using opposite polarity?

Tags: power-supply, dc, 12v, polarity

I have a device that requires input of 12V DC with positive polarity and a power supply that outputs 12V DC negative polarity (see figures below). Can I plug it in to try to see if it's working or will that harm the device?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the input polarity matter for a 12V DC adapter?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/113327/does-the-input-polarity-matter-for-a-12v-dc-adapter)

Comment: That's not an exact duplicate in one way but the same answers apply - it's not a good idea and you'll probably damage the device.

Comment: @Shimmy  You have to assume that with incorrect polarity of DC power supply (1) the device will not work and (2) the device will be permanently damaged and will become inoperable.  So, don't try it, if you are not sure that polarity is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the wrong polarity will very likely damage the device, if it is polarity-sensitive.  If the device has reverse-polarity protection, it won't work, but won't be damaged.